# Drag and drop feature in javascript

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

Could you help me please?

I would like to know how to support my website by adding a drag and drop feature using JavaScript. If anyone has useful references or examples; because I am totally blind in this area.

Thank you :)

The things that I have to do drag and drop could be a div or predifined object.

Answer (score 4):

If you are talking about file uploads with drag and drop I recommend using my library:

http://www.dropzonejs.com

It also supports image previews of dropped files and has a fallback for older browsers.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the simple code for dragging a/many files from your desktop to a web page and uploading on drop of the file.

Please note that it includes HTML5 options and so IE9 and lower doesn't support this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var dropbox = document.getElementById("dropbox")

    // init event handlers
    dropbox.addEventListener("dragenter", dragEnter, false);
    dropbox.addEventListener("dragexit", dragExit, false);
    dropbox.addEventListener("dragover", dragOver, false);
    dropbox.addEventListener("drop", drop, false);

    // init the widgets
    $("#progressbar").progressbar();
});

function dragEnter(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    evt.preventDefault();
}

function dragExit(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    evt.preventDefault();
}

function dragOver(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    evt.preventDefault();
}

function drop(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    evt.preventDefault();

    var files = evt.dataTransfer.files;
    var count = files.length;

    // Only call the handler if 1 or more files was dropped.
    if (count > 0)
        handleFiles(files);
}


function handleFiles(files) {
    var file = files[0];
    document.getElementById("droplabel").innerHTML = "Processing " + file.name;




    //  var sampleText = document.getElementById("sampleText").value;

     // var sampleFile = document.getElementById("sampleFile").files[0];

      var formdata = new FormData();

      formdata.append("sampleText", "ppppppp");

      formdata.append("sampleFile", file);

      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();       

      xhr.open("POST","/EHF/dataentry?", true);

      xhr.send(formdata);

      xhr.onload = function(e) {

          if (this.status == 200) {

             alert(this.responseText);

          }

      };   



    var reader = new FileReader();

    // init the reader event handlers
    reader.onprogress = handleReaderProgress;
    reader.onloadend = handleReaderLoadEnd;

    // begin the read operation
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}

function handleReaderProgress(evt) {
    if (evt.lengthComputable) {
        var loaded = (evt.loaded / evt.total);

        $("#progressbar").progressbar({ value: loaded * 100 });
    }
}

function handleReaderLoadEnd(evt) {
    $("#progressbar").progressbar({ value: 100 });

    var img = document.getElementById("preview");
    img.src = evt.target.result;
}
```

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dndimg.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery-ui-1.8.1.custom.css">
    <script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=ABQIAAAADYbHHQrNWPElNtE4hn2g1hQhn5tTlmnhbGVHENfXgw8ik0kvARSWpfuAdtdt1KqinQpUokxB7SpcsQ"
            type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.load("jquery", "1");
        google.load("jqueryui", "1");
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="draganddrop.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="dropbox"><span id="droplabel">Drop file here...</span>
    <div id="progressbar"></div>
</div>

<br/>
<img id="preview" src="" alt="[ preview will display here ]"/>
</body>
</html>
```

```
#dropbox {
    width: 425px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 2px solid #DDD;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    background-color: #FEFFEC;
    text-align: center;
    color: #BBB;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

#progressbar {
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    position: relative;
    top: 75%;
}

#droplabel {
    position: relative;
    top: 40%;
}
```

```
/*
* jQuery UI CSS Framework
* Copyright (c) 2010 AUTHORS.txt (http://jqueryui.com/about)
* Dual licensed under the MIT (MIT-LICENSE.txt) and GPL (GPL-LICENSE.txt) licenses.
*/

/* Layout helpers
----------------------------------*/
.ui-helper-hidden { display: none; }
.ui-helper-hidden-accessible { position: absolute; left: -99999999px; }
.ui-helper-reset { margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; outline: 0; line-height: 1.3; text-decoration: none; font-size: 100%; list-style: none; }
.ui-helper-clearfix:after { content: "."; display: block; height: 0; clear: both; visibility: hidden; }
.ui-helper-clearfix { display: inline-block; }
/* required comment for clearfix to work in Opera \*/
* html .ui-helper-clearfix { height:1%; }
.ui-helper-clearfix { display:block; }
/* end clearfix */
.ui-helper-zfix { width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0; left: 0; position: absolute; opacity: 0; filter:Alpha(Opacity=0); }


/* Interaction Cues
----------------------------------*/
.ui-state-disabled { cursor: default !important; }


/* Icons
----------------------------------*/

/* states and images */
.ui-icon { display: block; text-indent: -99999px; overflow: hidden; background-repeat: no-repeat; }


/* Misc visuals
----------------------------------*/

/* Overlays */
.ui-widget-overlay { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; }


/*
* jQuery UI CSS Framework
* Copyright (c) 2010 AUTHORS.txt (http://jqueryui.com/about)
* Dual licensed under the MIT (MIT-LICENSE.txt) and GPL (GPL-LICENSE.txt) licenses.
* To view and modify this theme, visit http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/?ffDefault=Lucida%20Grande,%20Lucida%20Sans,%20Arial,%20sans-serif&fwDefault=bold&fsDefault=1.1em&cornerRadius=6px&bgColorHeader=deedf7&bgTextureHeader=03_highlight_soft.png&bgImgOpacityHeader=100&borderColorHeader=aed0ea&fcHeader=222222&iconColorHeader=72a7cf&bgColorContent=f2f5f7&bgTextureContent=04_highlight_hard.png&bgImgOpacityContent=100&borderColorContent=dddddd&fcContent=362b36&iconColorContent=72a7cf&bgColorDefault=d7ebf9&bgTextureDefault=02_glass.png&bgImgOpacityDefault=80&borderColorDefault=aed0ea&fcDefault=2779aa&iconColorDefault=3d80b3&bgColorHover=e4f1fb&bgTextureHover=02_glass.png&bgImgOpacityHover=100&borderColorHover=74b2e2&fcHover=0070a3&iconColorHover=2694e8&bgColorActive=3baae3&bgTextureActive=02_glass.png&bgImgOpacityActive=50&borderColorActive=2694e8&fcActive=ffffff&iconColorActive=ffffff&bgColorHighlight=ffef8f&bgTextureHighlight=03_highlight_soft.png&bgImgOpacityHighlight=25&borderColorHighlight=f9dd34&fcHighlight=363636&iconColorHighlight=2e83ff&bgColorError=cd0a0a&bgTextureError=01_flat.png&bgImgOpacityError=15&borderColorError=cd0a0a&fcError=ffffff&iconColorError=ffffff&bgColorOverlay=eeeeee&bgTextureOverlay=08_diagonals_thick.png&bgImgOpacityOverlay=90&opacityOverlay=80&bgColorShadow=000000&bgTextureShadow=04_highlight_hard.png&bgImgOpacityShadow=70&opacityShadow=30&thicknessShadow=7px&offsetTopShadow=-7px&offsetLeftShadow=-7px&cornerRadiusShadow=8px
*/


/* Component containers
----------------------------------*/
.ui-widget { font-family: Lucida Grande, Lucida Sans, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 1.1em; }
.ui-widget .ui-widget { font-size: 1em; }
.ui-widget input, .ui-widget select, .ui-widget textarea, .ui-widget button { font-family: Lucida Grande, Lucida Sans, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 1em; }
.ui-widget-content { border: 1px solid #dddddd; background: #f2f5f7 url(images/ui-bg_highlight-hard_100_f2f5f7_1x100.png) 50% top repeat-x; color: #362b36; }
.ui-widget-content a { color: #362b36; }
.ui-widget-header { border: 1px solid #aed0ea; background: #deedf7 url(images/ui-bg_highlight-soft_100_deedf7_1x100.png) 50% 50% repeat-x; color: #222222; font-weight: bold; }
.ui-widget-header a { color: #222222; }

/* Interaction states
----------------------------------*/
.ui-state-default, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-default, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-default { border: 1px solid #aed0ea; background: #d7ebf9 url(images/ui-bg_glass_80_d7ebf9_1x400.png) 50% 50% repeat-x; font-weight: bold; color: #2779aa; }
.ui-state-default a, .ui-state-default a:link, .ui-state-default a:visited { color: #2779aa; text-decoration: none; }
.ui-state-hover, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-hover, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-hover, .ui-state-focus, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-focus, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-focus { border: 1px solid #74b2e2; background: #e4f1fb url(images/ui-bg_glass_100_e4f1fb_1x400.png) 50% 50% repeat-x; font-weight: bold; color: #0070a3; }
.ui-state-hover a, .ui-state-hover a:hover { color: #0070a3; text-decoration: none; }
.ui-state-active, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-active, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-active { border: 1px solid #2694e8; background: #3baae3 url(images/ui-bg_glass_50_3baae3_1x400.png) 50% 50% repeat-x; font-weight: bold; color: #ffffff; }
.ui-state-active a, .ui-state-active a:link, .ui-state-active a:visited { color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none; }
.ui-widget :active { outline: none; }

/* Interaction Cues
----------------------------------*/
.ui-state-highlight, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-highlight, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-highlight  {border: 1px solid #f9dd34; background: #ffef8f url(images/ui-bg_highlight-soft_25_ffef8f_1x100.png) 50% top repeat-x; color: #363636; }
.ui-state-highlight a, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-highlight a,.ui-widget-header .ui-state-highlight a { color: #363636; }
.ui-state-error, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-error, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-error {border: 1px solid #cd0a0a; background: #cd0a0a url(images/ui-bg_flat_15_cd0a0a_40x100.png) 50% 50% repeat-x; color: #ffffff; }
.ui-state-error a, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-error a, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-error a { color: #ffffff; }
.ui-state-error-text, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-error-text, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-error-text { color: #ffffff; }
.ui-priority-primary, .ui-widget-content .ui-priority-primary, .ui-widget-header .ui-priority-primary { font-weight: bold; }
.ui-priority-secondary, .ui-widget-content .ui-priority-secondary,  .ui-widget-header .ui-priority-secondary { opacity: .7; filter:Alpha(Opacity=70); font-weight: normal; }
.ui-state-disabled, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-disabled, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-disabled { opacity: .35; filter:Alpha(Opacity=35); background-image: none; }

/* Icons
----------------------------------*/

/* states and images */
.ui-icon { width: 16px; height: 16px; background-image: url(images/ui-icons_72a7cf_256x240.png); }
.ui-widget-content .ui-icon {background-image: url(images/ui-icons_72a7cf_256x240.png); }
.ui-widget-header .ui-icon {background-image: url(images/ui-icons_72a7cf_256x240.png); }
.ui-state-default .ui-icon { background-image: url(images/ui-icons_3d80b3_256x240.png); }
.ui-state-hover .ui-icon, .ui-state-focus .ui-icon {background-image: url(images/ui-icons_2694e8_256x240.png); }
.ui-state-active .ui-icon {background-image: url(images/ui-icons_ffffff_256x240.png); }
.ui-state-highlight .ui-icon {background-image: url(images/ui-icons_2e83ff_256x240.png); }
.ui-state-error .ui-icon, .ui-state-error-text .ui-icon {background-image: url(images/ui-icons_ffffff_256x240.png); }

/* positioning */
.ui-icon-carat-1-n { background-position: 0 0; }
.ui-icon-carat-1-ne { background-position: -16px 0; }
.ui-icon-carat-1-e { background-position: -32px 0; }
.ui-icon-carat-1-se { background-position: -48px 0; }
.ui-icon-carat-1-s { background-position: -64px 0; }
.ui-icon-carat-1-sw { background-position: -80px 0; }
.ui-icon-carat-1-w { background-position: -96px 0; }
.ui-icon-carat-1-nw { background-position: -112px 0; }
.ui-icon-carat-2-n-s { background-position: -128px 0; }
.ui-icon-carat-2-e-w { background-position: -144px 0; }
.ui-icon-triangle-1-n { background-position: 0 -16px; }
.ui-icon-triangle-1-ne { background-position: -16px -16px; }
.ui-icon-triangle-1-e { background-position: -32px -16px; }
.ui-icon-triangle-1-se { background-position: -48px -16px; }
.ui-icon-triangle-1-s { background-position: -64px -16px; }
.ui-icon-triangle-1-sw { background-position: -80px -16px; }
.ui-icon-triangle-1-w { background-position: -96px -16px; }
.ui-icon-triangle-1-nw { background-position: -112px -16px; }
.ui-icon-triangle-2-n-s { background-position: -128px -16px; }
.ui-icon-triangle-2-e-w { background-position: -144px -16px; }
.ui-icon-arrow-1-n { background-position: 0 -32px; }
.ui-icon-arrow-1-ne { background-position: -16px -32px; }
.ui-icon-arrow-1-e { background-position: -32px -32px; }
.ui-icon-arrow-1-se { background-position: -48px -32px; }
.ui-icon-arrow-1-s { background-position: -64px -32px; }
.ui-icon-arrow-1-sw { background-position: -80px -32px; }
.ui-icon-arrow-1-w { background-position: -96px -32px; }
.ui-icon-arrow-1-nw { background-position: -112px -32px; }
.ui-icon-arrow-2-n-s { background-position: -128px -32px; }
.ui-icon-arrow-2-ne-sw { background-position: -144px -32px; }
.ui-icon-arrow-2-e-w { background-position: -160px -32px; }
.ui-icon-arrow-2-se-nw { background-position: -176px -32px; }
.ui-icon-arrowstop-1-n { background-position: -192px -32px; }
.ui-icon-arrowstop-1-e { background-position: -208px -32px; }
.ui-icon-arrowstop-1-s { background-position: -224px -32px; }
.ui-icon-arrowstop-1-w { background-position: -240px -32px; }
.ui-icon-arrowthick-1-n { background-position: 0 -48px; }
.ui-icon-arrowthick-1-ne { background-position: -16px -48px; }
.ui-icon-arrowthick-1-e { background-position: -32px -48px; }
.ui-icon-arrowthick-1-se { background-position: -48px -48px; }
.ui-icon-arrowthick-1-s { background-position: -64px -48px; }
.ui-icon-arrowthick-1-sw { background-position: -80px -48px; }
.ui-icon-arrowthick-1-w { background-position: -96px -48px; }
.ui-icon-arrowthick-1-nw { background-position: -112px -48px; }
.ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s { background-position: -128px -48px; }
.ui-icon-arrowthick-2-ne-sw { background-position: -144px -48px; }
.ui-icon-arrowthick-2-e-w { background-position: -160px -48px; }
.ui-icon-arrowthick-2-se-nw { background-position: -176px -48px; }
.ui-icon-arrowthickstop-1-n { background-position: -192px -48px; }
.ui-icon-arrowthickstop-1-e { background-position: -208px -48px; }
.ui-icon-arrowthickstop-1-s { background-position: -224px -48px; }
.ui-icon-arrowthickstop-1-w { background-position: -240px -48px; }
.ui-icon-arrowreturnthick-1-w { background-position: 0 -64px; }
.ui-icon-arrowreturnthick-1-n { background-position: -16px -64px; }
.ui-icon-arrowreturnthick-1-e { background-position: -32px -64px; }
.ui-icon-arrowreturnthick-1-s { background-position: -48px -64px; }
.ui-icon-arrowreturn-1-w { background-position: -64px -64px; }
.ui-icon-arrowreturn-1-n { background-position: -80px -64px; }
.ui-icon-arrowreturn-1-e { background-position: -96px -64px; }
.ui-icon-arrowreturn-1-s { background-position: -112px -64px; }
.ui-icon-arrowrefresh-1-w { background-position: -128px -64px; }
.ui-icon-arrowrefresh-1-n { background-position: -144px -64px; }
.ui-icon-arrowrefresh-1-e { background-position: -160px -64px; }
.ui-icon-arrowrefresh-1-s { background-position: -176px -64px; }
.ui-icon-arrow-4 { background-position: 0 -80px; }
.ui-icon-arrow-4-diag { background-position: -16px -80px; }
.ui-icon-extlink { background-position: -32px -80px; }
.ui-icon-newwin { background-position: -48px -80px; }
.ui-icon-refresh { background-position: -64px -80px; }
.ui-icon-shuffle { background-position: -80px -80px; }
.ui-icon-transfer-e-w { background-position: -96px -80px; }
.ui-icon-transferthick-e-w { background-position: -112px -80px; }
.ui-icon-folder-collapsed { background-position: 0 -96px; }
.ui-icon-folder-open { background-position: -16px -96px; }
.ui-icon-document { background-position: -32px -96px; }
.ui-icon-document-b { background-position: -48px -96px; }
.ui-icon-note { background-position: -64px -96px; }
.ui-icon-mail-closed { background-position: -80px -96px; }
.ui-icon-mail-open { background-position: -96px -96px; }
.ui-icon-suitcase { background-position: -112px -96px; }
.ui-icon-comment { background-position: -128px -96px; }
.ui-icon-person { background-position: -144px -96px; }
.ui-icon-print { background-position: -160px -96px; }
.ui-icon-trash { background-position: -176px -96px; }
.ui-icon-locked { background-position: -192px -96px; }
.ui-icon-unlocked { background-position: -208px -96px; }
.ui-icon-bookmark { background-position: -224px -96px; }
.ui-icon-tag { background-position: -240px -96px; }
.ui-icon-home { background-position: 0 -112px; }
.ui-icon-flag { background-position: -16px -112px; }
.ui-icon-calendar { background-position: -32px -112px; }
.ui-icon-cart { background-position: -48px -112px; }
.ui-icon-pencil { background-position: -64px -112px; }
.ui-icon-clock { background-position: -80px -112px; }
.ui-icon-disk { background-position: -96px -112px; }
.ui-icon-calculator { background-position: -112px -112px; }
.ui-icon-zoomin { background-position: -128px -112px; }
.ui-icon-zoomout { background-position: -144px -112px; }
.ui-icon-search { background-position: -160px -112px; }
.ui-icon-wrench { background-position: -176px -112px; }
.ui-icon-gear { background-position: -192px -112px; }
.ui-icon-heart { background-position: -208px -112px; }
.ui-icon-star { background-position: -224px -112px; }
.ui-icon-link { background-position: -240px -112px; }
.ui-icon-cancel { background-position: 0 -128px; }
.ui-icon-plus { background-position: -16px -128px; }
.ui-icon-plusthick { background-position: -32px -128px; }
.ui-icon-minus { background-position: -48px -128px; }
.ui-icon-minusthick { background-position: -64px -128px; }
.ui-icon-close { background-position: -80px -128px; }
.ui-icon-closethick { background-position: -96px -128px; }
.ui-icon-key { background-position: -112px -128px; }
.ui-icon-lightbulb { background-position: -128px -128px; }
.ui-icon-scissors { background-position: -144px -128px; }
.ui-icon-clipboard { background-position: -160px -128px; }
.ui-icon-copy { background-position: -176px -128px; }
.ui-icon-contact { background-position: -192px -128px; }
.ui-icon-image { background-position: -208px -128px; }
.ui-icon-video { background-position: -224px -128px; }
.ui-icon-script { background-position: -240px -128px; }
.ui-icon-alert { background-position: 0 -144px; }
.ui-icon-info { background-position: -16px -144px; }
.ui-icon-notice { background-position: -32px -144px; }
.ui-icon-help { background-position: -48px -144px; }
.ui-icon-check { background-position: -64px -144px; }
.ui-icon-bullet { background-position: -80px -144px; }
.ui-icon-radio-off { background-position: -96px -144px; }
.ui-icon-radio-on { background-position: -112px -144px; }
.ui-icon-pin-w { background-position: -128px -144px; }
.ui-icon-pin-s { background-position: -144px -144px; }
.ui-icon-play { background-position: 0 -160px; }
.ui-icon-pause { background-position: -16px -160px; }
.ui-icon-seek-next { background-position: -32px -160px; }
.ui-icon-seek-prev { background-position: -48px -160px; }
.ui-icon-seek-end { background-position: -64px -160px; }
.ui-icon-seek-start { background-position: -80px -160px; }
/* ui-icon-seek-first is deprecated, use ui-icon-seek-start instead */
.ui-icon-seek-first { background-position: -80px -160px; }
.ui-icon-stop { background-position: -96px -160px; }
.ui-icon-eject { background-position: -112px -160px; }
.ui-icon-volume-off { background-position: -128px -160px; }
.ui-icon-volume-on { background-position: -144px -160px; }
.ui-icon-power { background-position: 0 -176px; }
.ui-icon-signal-diag { background-position: -16px -176px; }
.ui-icon-signal { background-position: -32px -176px; }
.ui-icon-battery-0 { background-position: -48px -176px; }
.ui-icon-battery-1 { background-position: -64px -176px; }
.ui-icon-battery-2 { background-position: -80px -176px; }
.ui-icon-battery-3 { background-position: -96px -176px; }
.ui-icon-circle-plus { background-position: 0 -192px; }
.ui-icon-circle-minus { background-position: -16px -192px; }
.ui-icon-circle-close { background-position: -32px -192px; }
.ui-icon-circle-triangle-e { background-position: -48px -192px; }
.ui-icon-circle-triangle-s { background-position: -64px -192px; }
.ui-icon-circle-triangle-w { background-position: -80px -192px; }
.ui-icon-circle-triangle-n { background-position: -96px -192px; }
.ui-icon-circle-arrow-e { background-position: -112px -192px; }
.ui-icon-circle-arrow-s { background-position: -128px -192px; }
.ui-icon-circle-arrow-w { background-position: -144px -192px; }
.ui-icon-circle-arrow-n { background-position: -160px -192px; }
.ui-icon-circle-zoomin { background-position: -176px -192px; }
.ui-icon-circle-zoomout { background-position: -192px -192px; }
.ui-icon-circle-check { background-position: -208px -192px; }
.ui-icon-circlesmall-plus { background-position: 0 -208px; }
.ui-icon-circlesmall-minus { background-position: -16px -208px; }
.ui-icon-circlesmall-close { background-position: -32px -208px; }
.ui-icon-squaresmall-plus { background-position: -48px -208px; }
.ui-icon-squaresmall-minus { background-position: -64px -208px; }
.ui-icon-squaresmall-close { background-position: -80px -208px; }
.ui-icon-grip-dotted-vertical { background-position: 0 -224px; }
.ui-icon-grip-dotted-horizontal { background-position: -16px -224px; }
.ui-icon-grip-solid-vertical { background-position: -32px -224px; }
.ui-icon-grip-solid-horizontal { background-position: -48px -224px; }
.ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se { background-position: -64px -224px; }
.ui-icon-grip-diagonal-se { background-position: -80px -224px; }


/* Misc visuals
----------------------------------*/

/* Corner radius */
.ui-corner-tl { -moz-border-radius-topleft: 6px; -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 6px; border-top-left-radius: 6px; }
.ui-corner-tr { -moz-border-radius-topright: 6px; -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 6px; border-top-right-radius: 6px; }
.ui-corner-bl { -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 6px; -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 6px; border-bottom-left-radius: 6px; }
.ui-corner-br { -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 6px; -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 6px; border-bottom-right-radius: 6px; }
.ui-corner-top { -moz-border-radius-topleft: 6px; -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 6px; border-top-left-radius: 6px; -moz-border-radius-topright: 6px; -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 6px; border-top-right-radius: 6px; }
.ui-corner-bottom { -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 6px; -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 6px; border-bottom-left-radius: 6px; -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 6px; -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 6px; border-bottom-right-radius: 6px; }
.ui-corner-right {  -moz-border-radius-topright: 6px; -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 6px; border-top-right-radius: 6px; -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 6px; -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 6px; border-bottom-right-radius: 6px; }
.ui-corner-left { -moz-border-radius-topleft: 6px; -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 6px; border-top-left-radius: 6px; -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 6px; -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 6px; border-bottom-left-radius: 6px; }
.ui-corner-all { -moz-border-radius: 6px; -webkit-border-radius: 6px; border-radius: 6px; }

/* Overlays */
.ui-widget-overlay { background: #eeeeee url(images/ui-bg_diagonals-thick_90_eeeeee_40x40.png) 50% 50% repeat; opacity: .80;filter:Alpha(Opacity=80); }
.ui-widget-shadow { margin: -7px 0 0 -7px; padding: 7px; background: #000000 url(images/ui-bg_highlight-hard_70_000000_1x100.png) 50% top repeat-x; opacity: .30;filter:Alpha(Opacity=30); -moz-border-radius: 8px; -webkit-border-radius: 8px; border-radius: 8px; }
```

```
public class FileUploader extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
        try {

            ArrayList<Object> items =  (ArrayList<Object>) new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(request);
            FileItem  curntFile=null;
            for(int iCount=0;iCount<items.size();iCount++){
               curntFile=  (FileItem)items.get(iCount);

               dir = dir+curntFile.getName();                        
               OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File ( dir ));            
               InputStream inputStream = curntFile.getInputStream();
               int read = 0;
               byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
               while ((read = inputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                out.write(bytes, 0, read);
                }
               inputStream.close();
               out.flush();
               out.close();
               uploadedFilesResult=curntFile.getName();
           }

        } catch (FileUploadException e) {
           throw new ServletException("Parsing file upload failed.", e);
        }
        response.getWriter().print(uploadedFilesResult);


    }
}
```

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>DataEntry</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.tcs.Webframework.ehf.action.FileUploader</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>DataEntry</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/dataentry</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few simple tutorials on how to implement drag-and-drop using just javascript:

[Drag and Drop using Javascript](http://www.webreference.com/programming/javascript/mk/column2/)

[Javascript Drag and Drop](http://luke.breuer.com/tutorial/javascript-drag-and-drop-tutorial.aspx)

The following utilize jQuery plugins, which might be a bit easier to implement if you are interested in using them :

[jQuery Drag and Drop Tutorials](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/freebies/drag-drop-jquery-plugins/)

Answer (score 0):

I've used Scriptaculous, which uses Web 2.0, and JSON data object translation

http://script.aculo.us/

They provide good documentation, and good examples to get you started

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example for this feature. It is very easy in HTML 5.

**Script**:

```
<script>
function allowDrop(ev) {
ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
ev.preventDefault();
var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<br>
<img id="drag1" src="img_logo.gif" draggable="true"    ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69">
```

**CSS:**

```
<style>
#div1 {width:350px;height:70px;padding:10px;border:1px solid #aaaaaa;}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest usage of the [drag and Drop API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API) with multiples elements.

This will attach the events to all elements with a class `movable` and `receiver`, and should works on all kind of devices.

Notice the attribute `draggable` set dynamically on elements with the class `movable`.

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".movable").forEach(function(e){
  e.setAttribute("draggable", true)
  e.addEventListener("dragstart" , moveFUNC , false)
})

document.querySelectorAll(".receiver").forEach(function(e){
  e.addEventListener("drop" , dropFUNC , false)
  e.addEventListener("dragover" , dragFUNC , false)
})

function moveFUNC(e){
 e.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", e.target.outerHTML)
}

function dragFUNC(e){
 e.preventDefault()
 e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "move"
}

function dropFUNC(e){
 e.preventDefault()
 e.target.innerHTML += e.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain")
}
```

```css
.receiver {
 border: 1px black solid;
 height:10vh;
 width:14%;
 display:inline-block
}

.movable {
 border: 1px black solid;
 width:12%
}
```

```html
<div class="movable">Movable</div>
<div class="movable">Movable</div>
<div class="movable">Hello</div>
<div class="movable">World</div>

<div class="receiver"></div>
<div class="receiver"></div>
<div class="receiver"></div>
<div class="receiver"></div>
<div class="receiver"></div>
```